# How to install apps by connecting to the desktop

Tags: google-play-store, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

I was just wondering is that possible to install apps on my tablet by connecting it to my dekstop from google play.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it shouldn't be necessary to connect the tablet to your desktop. All you need to do is to log into Google Play on your desktop with the same account that's registered on the tablet. Then navigate to an app and press the `Install` button (or `Installed` if it's already installed on one of your other devices):

[image: Screenshot of Install portion of Google Play page]

Once you click `Install`, a dialog will appear which allows you to select the device to install to:

[image]

After clicking `Install`, click `OK` on the next dialog that pops up. Then connect your tablet via WiFi, wait a bit, and the app will be installed!